# readr issue with read_delim not including decimals

Tags: r, readr

I'm trying to read a csv file that looks like this (Let's call this `test1.csv`)

```
test_1;test_2;test_3;test_4
Test with Ö Ä;20;10,45;15,34
```

As you can see, the values are separated by `;` and not `,` - in fact `,` is the decimal separator. I've added "Ö" and "Ä" because my data has German letters in it - requiring me to use ISO-8859-1 in the `locale()` in `read_delim()`. Note, this isn't as important, it just explains why I want to use `read_delim()`.

Now I would read all this using `read_delim()`:

```r
read_delim("test1.csv", delim = ";", locale = locale(encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', 
           decimal_mark = ","))
```

Giving me this:

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  test_1              test_2 test_3 test_4
  <chr>               <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 "Test with Ö Ä"     20   10.4   15.3
```

And indeed, I can get the 10.45 value out by using `pull(test_3)`:
`[1] 10.45`

But now if I simply add five 0s to the `10.45` making it `1000000.45` like so (let's call this `test2.csv`)

```
test_1;test_2;test_3;test_4
Test with Ö Ä;20;1000000,45;15,34
```

And then repeat everything, I **completely lose the `.45`** behind the `1000000`.

```r
read_delim("test2.csv", delim = ";",locale = locale(encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',decimal_mark = ",")) %>% pull(test_3)
Rows: 1 Columns: 4                                                                                                    
 0s── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Delimiter: ";"
chr (1): test_1
dbl (3): test_2, test_3, test_4

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
[1] 1000000
```

I must be able to retain this information, no? Or control this behaviour? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a printing issue.

If you add `%>% print(digits = 22)` to the end of your workflow you get:

```r
[1] 1000000.449999999953434
```

- this is not 1000000.45 because what's shown is the closest approximation available in the standard floating-point system;
- the default `getOption("digits")` value is 7; you can set this however you like with `options(digits = <your_choice>)`. In this case anything between `digits = 10`  and `digits = 17` will get you a printed result of "1000000.45"; `digits = 18` starts to reveal the underlying approximation.

Comment: I would be shocked if there wasn't a duplicate of this somewhere, but I can't find it (this is **not** the same as "why aren't these numbers equal" ?)

Comment: Ahh such a rookie mistake... Right, I'm glad then, many thanks for your answer! I feel this is then probably not a fantastic question to remain available - in the end it has nothing to do with `readr`...